# Spotify Renew Session Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, spotify, access-token, option-type

Attempting to renew session from Spotify so I can retrieve new access and refresh  token. Starting on the first print line, I receive the fatal error.

```
@IBAction func renewSession(sender: AnyObject) {

    let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
    auth.tokenRefreshURL = NSURL(string: tokenRefresh)
    auth.tokenSwapURL = NSURL(string: tokenSwap)
    auth.session = self.spotifySession
    auth.sessionUserDefaultsKey = sessionKey

    if (auth.session != nil) {

        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session, callback: {(error, session) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                print("The renewed Spotify session is", session)
                print("The renewed canonical user name in the session is", session.canonicalUsername)
                print("The renewed access Spotify token in session is - %@", auth.session.accessToken)
                print("The renewed encrypted refresh Spotify token in session is - %@", auth.session.encryptedRefreshToken)
                print("The renewed expiration date of the Spotify access token is - %@", auth.session.expirationDate)

            } else {

                print ("The problem with the renewal session is", error)

            }

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be checking `if session != nil`, not `if error != nil`. There is some `error` but your code is moving control to the incorrect flow.